# I have an existing ERC721A smart contract deployed but how can I change public mint price and open that contract?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-721, mint

My team and I deployed an ERC721A smart contract months ago and we need to open that contract and change the public mint price on that which is mutable because we have done that before too but the core developer who did this before left our team and we need an urgent help of how we can open the contract again and change just the public mint price.

It'll be great if you can just help us with this since it's really important. Thank you!

Comment: I hope you are aware that a new contract will be generated after the changes, and you will lose all the data that was on the previous contract?

Comment: We have edited the mint price before as well but it was on the same contract, we just updated it by paying the gas fees and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function in your contract named `updatePublicSalePrice()`, which lets you update the price of your public sale.

```
function updatePublicSalePrice(uint256 _newPrice) public onlyOwner {
        PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE = _newPrice;
    }
```

Now you have 2 ways in which you can actually change the price:

1. Go to `etherscan` to your verified contract. There will be a tab `write` there in which you can access all the functions of your contract (the write functions). Here, find the `updatePublicSalePrice()` function and connect your `metamask` wallet to the explorer. Now you can add your new price in the input and write the transaction.
2. The second way is to import your contract in `remix`, connect your wallet to it, and create an instance of the contract with the deployed address. Here, you can access all the functions of the contract and can follow the same procedure as point 1.

Just make sure to input the price value in `wei`, ie., multiply your input with 10**18. So if you want to change the price to 1.2 Ether, it should be 1.2 * 10 ** 18 (or 12 * 10 ** 17).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am able to update the price. Have a good day and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two possible ways

1. Update Price in Existing contract
2. Deploy new contract with updated price

**Updating the Price**

First of all go to [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6358f271817b890d64b66574d7e7061142e4f31b#code) and open the contract
Now go to the option of write contract as shown below
[image]
After this click `connect to web3` option to connect your metamask wallet to the etherscan

**NOTE : CONNECT SAME WALLET THAT WAS USED TO DEPLOY THE CONTRACT**

Now scroll down to the 18th Function named `updatePublicSalePrice` and click on it

[image]
Now go to [EthConverter](https://eth-converter.com/) and convert the new amount from ethereum into wei

Enter the new price in wei here and click write

Now approve the transaction after the metamask popup will open

Soon after the completion of transaction the price will be updated

**Deploying Contract with Updated Price**

First of all go to [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6358f271817b890d64b66574d7e7061142e4f31b#code) and open that contract code

Then copy the code from there and paste the code in [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/) by creating a new file

Now go to Line No. 2221

```
uint256 public PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE = .1 ether;
```

and replace the `.1 ether` with the new price you want

Now press `CTRL+S` to compile and move on to deploy the contract using injected Web3 option using your Metamask Wallet

Comment: Sure 

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6358f271817b890d64b66574d7e7061142e4f31b

Comment: Updated the Answer you can check now

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am able to update the price. Have a good day and thank you!

Comment: Welcome sir ! Up vote would be appreciated if I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

I see you ave `updatePublicSalePrice` in the contract in 18th number function. Using that you can update the mint sale price.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6358f271817b890d64b66574d7e7061142e4f31b#writeContract

The amount set should be in wei like if you want to make price `1 ether` than you have to enter `1000000000000000000`.

Comment: But where do I open this contract and edit it, if you can help me with it? I will be able to do it ASAP

Comment: Line number 2221, you will find code `uint256 public PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE = .1 ether;`
If you want to change price to 1 ether then `uint256 public PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE = 1 ether;`

Comment: Thank you for this info but which website or tool will I need in order to load this contract and edit it, that's the main problem I am facing. Can I edit it using remix or will I need another tool?

Comment: Yes you can use any text editor or remix.

Comment: Thanks a lot Safi, can you just quickly answer me on how do I load this contract and edit on remix or any text editor? I am not able to find this information or any related video anywhere, this will solve my whole problem.

Comment: Copy the contract source code from here https://etherscan.io/address/0x6358f271817b890d64b66574d7e7061142e4f31b#code

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am able to update the price. Have a good day and thank you!